# How do i minimize the CSS file size?

Tags: html, css

I have built a site named http://typingtutorfree.com/. How do I minimize the CSS file size? It's taking so much time to load the site. Is there any other way to make it load faster? Please give me some solution to make my site load fast.

Comment: What is the file size of your CSS?

Comment: Are you sure its the CSS file that takes so long to load?

Comment: Minimize the CSS file ?. from your site URL i dont see much in CSS.

Comment: large `css` file? are you sure?

Comment: after a quick check on the site, it isn't the css that slows down the site. It is the 35(!) js files and the error.wav that are slowing it down.

Comment: First thing first css never takes this long as your site is taking, the time taking thing in here is your jquery/JavaScript and audio file

Answer (score 1):

[image: printscreen of loading times.]

Your CSS takes about 200ms seconds to load, so the problem isn't located there. You have quite a lot of javascript/jquery files though (quick count: 35 of them), and you can minify those to speed up some things. You should also check if you really need all 35 of them, and remove those that you don't need.

You can minify JS files with a lot of tools (if you use dreamweaver or visual studio, there is a minifier included), or on the internet.

Google has a tool for this: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home Or you have other sites who offer the same service: [example](http://jscompress.com/) , [another one](http://javascript-minifier.com/), [third example](http://refresh-sf.com/).

The last one also compresses your css, if you'd want that.

A last point of advice: check that `error.wav` file, because it takes quite a lot of time to load. See if you can't compress it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option would be to concatenate any CSS blocks you can. Duplicate styling will only cause the load speed to be longer.

If your CSS code is already as minimal as it can be, sites such as http://csscompressor.net/ can remove new-lines and other code formalities, making the output unreadable but considerably smaller.

Your website may be unable to distribute the CSS with speed due to the server's limitations on its up-link. There are many services out there such as CloudFlare which are able to cache a multitude of files, including CSS, and send it to the browser with much less loading times.

Comment: well i have tried with  http://csscompressor.com/ but, unfortunally not working :(

Comment: Then I'd believe it's not your CSS, possibly a different asset being accessed on an external server. You can still give CloudFlare a go if all else fails :)

Comment: @Leothelion please don't use the comments of an answer as chat. :) (and gratz on your first answer, Nunnsy)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the file size of your CSS files by removing unnecessary white-spaces, line breaks, indentations, comments, semicolons, quotes and by combining rules when possible.

I personally use an online tool like https://compresscss.net/ to make things easier.